# How to use ‘concerns’ in the sentence?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

This is the original sentence:

> **This novel has to do with peasant life after the reform.**

We cannot say

> This novel concerns peasant life after the reform.

but we can say

> This is a novel concerning peasant life after the reform.

What is the difference between the second sentence and the third?  How to understand the meaning of the word ‘concerns’?

Comment: Why do you think we can't say "This novel concerns peasant life after the reform"?

Comment: @AIQ The book says: They have different meanings.

Comment: Y. zeng, yes that is something you can include in your question; doing so will help us understand your problem better. What does your book say? And which book?

Comment: @AIQ This book’s ISBN is 9787560019406. It does not say it clearly. For I am a student, I can not tell the difference.

Comment: @Y.zengThat's 'New Concept English' apparently.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian yes

Comment: @Y.zeng I edited my answer. I hope it's useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can say either. They are both correct English, but they answer slightly different questions.

**Question:**
What is that novel about?
**Answer:**
This novel concerns peasant life after the reform.

**Question:**
What have you got in your hand?
or
What is that book?
**Answer:**
This is a novel concerning peasant life after the reform.

You asked about the word 'contains'. I assume you meant the word 'concerns'.
As the first definition [HERE](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/concern) explains, it means 'relates to' or 'is about'.

This novel is about peasant life...
This is a novel about peasant life...
This novel concerns peasant life...
This is a novel concerning peasant life...